# Un/Check checkbox in table found by name (table value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I want to Check or Uncheck an Checkbox which is part of an tr.

From this tr I already have the Name as Information.

I need something like "Uncheck checkbox on tr where tr.name = $name"

```
<tr>
    <td id="klauselname">
            002  
    </td>
    <td>
            50591
    </td>
    <td>
            Text
    </td>
    <td id="td-center">
            <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="klauselname">
            003  
    </td>
    <td>
            50601
    </td>
    <td>
            Text
    </td>
    <td id="td-center">
            <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Do u have any idea? o.o

Comment: You are using the same DOM ID multiple times in your code. Avoid that, this leads to several bugs.

Comment: You have invalid HTML; two elements with the same `id` property-value is not allowed. Instead you should use a class-name. As to the other part of the question: yes, we have an idea. But what went wrong in your own attempted code? What code did you try?

Comment: You're re-using the same `id` which is invalid, and neither of the checkboxes have a `name` attribute

Comment: yeah using id instead of class is not optimal at this point. I will change that soon. The input types comes from razor via foreach and Html.DisplayFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , as others pointed out , IDs in your DOM should always be unique. You can use classes or other attributes for mass manipulation , but not IDs.

So lets clear the duplicate ids like this and at the same time add some IDs on your Checkboxes.

```
<tr>
 <td id="myUniqueID_1">002</td>
 <td>50591</td>
 <td>Text</td>
 <td class="td-center" id="myUniqueID_3">
   <input id='myCheckBox_1' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="myUniqueID_2">003</td>
 <td>50601</td>
 <td>Text</td>
 <td class="td-center" id="myUniqueID_4">
   <input id='myCheckBox_2' class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

now we can add a function that will take care the Checkbox changes. We will use the checked property and will change it to **false** or **true** depending on our needs.

```
<script>
  function changeState(elID){
    var myCheckBoxStatus = document.getElementById(elID).checked;

    if(myCheckBoxStatus)
      document.getElementById(elID).checked = false;
    else
      document.getElementById(elID).checked = true;
  }
</script>
```

and lets also place a button to test it out

```
<button onclick='changeState("myCheckBox_2");'>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After i edited my razor code i was able to add an ID which i can use now. And of course I changed all IDs to classes ^^